# what could be draining my battery on my Chevrolet Silverado

Tags: battery, chevrolet, silverado

I need to know what could be draining my battery in my 1997 Chevrolet Silverado

Comment: Give us a better idea of exactly what is happening? When does it drain, overnight? There are *way* too many answers as it is. Help us out here a little bit. Just edit your post and put it in there.

Answer (score 1):

it could be the alternator. it could not be charging the battery because it could be seize up or the belt on the alternator could not be rotating the alternator to charge the battery. it might even be a bad battery. it could be alot of things. it could even be an electrical problem where something is shorting out and draining the battery. we would need more information to trim down the reasons why it is draining.